# How to count more than one time with different conditions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query, group-by

Having a table like this:

[image: Example table]

I want to get a result like this:

[image: Result]

Something like:

```
SELECT ParentId, COUNT(SomeValue = 1) [CountMin], COUNT(SomeValue > 1) [CountRest]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ParentId
```

Comment: Are you explicitly looking for the count of the value `1`, or the count of whatever value is the minimum value? To put it another way, if you change all the `1` rows to `2`, is the answer `0 | 7` or `4 | 3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SUM(CASE...)

```
SELECT
    ParentID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SomeValue = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountMin,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SomeValue <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountRest
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    ParentID = 123;
```